# no internet through wwan0 when cable attached to eth0

Tags: linux, networking, angstrom

On my Beaglebone card I run Angstrom Linux. It has one cable in the ethernet port (etho) and a USB 3G modem dongle in the USB port whose interface is named wwan0.

At the other end of the crossover ethernet cable is another Linux computer running on Raspberry Pi.

When the ethernet cable is disconnected, I have internet access, but when the cable is attached, internet traffic gets directed on the eth0 interface.

The ip route table looks like this:

```
root@beaglebone:~# ip route
default dev eth0  scope link
default via 95.192.114.29 dev wwan0
95.192.114.28/30 dev wwan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 95.192.114.30
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.29.204
```

When doing
    ping 8.8.8.8
this fails, but when I do

```
ping -I wwan0 8.8.8.8
```

This works fine. I can also ping

```
ping 169.254.1.N # 'far' end of ethernet crossover cable
```

which is the other end of the ethernet crossover cable and it works. So how do I make sure that internet traffic goes out on the right interface? Is this one of the cases where the "Advanced router" option must be selected in menuconfig before recompiling the kernel? Or is it enough to swap the order between the two default routes?

This card doesn't route any data coming from somewhere else, it receives data on an I2C bus and is supposed to write this data to one server on the internet and another server on the other end of the crossover cable.

```
/etc/network/interfaces
iface eth0 inet static
    address 169.254.1.N+1 # 'near' end of crossover cable
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    gateway 169.254.1.2

allow-hotplug wwan0
iface wwan0 inet dhcp
```

Another issue which might be related is that the IP address isn't correctly set to the static one I set in /etc/network/interfaces above, it's on the correct subnet 169.254.0.X but it isn't what I statically configured.

### EDIT 4

If I try to delete the default route under EDIT 2

```
route del default gw 0.0.0.0 dev eth0
```

`connman` jumps into action and immediately re-adds it again, as visible via `journalctl`:

```
beaglebone connmand[853]: eth0 {del} route 0.0.0.0 gw 0.0.0.0 scope 0 <UNIVERSE>
beaglebone connmand[853]: eth0 {add} route 0.0.0.0 gw 0.0.0.0 scope 0 <UNIVERSE>
```

(the timestamps of those two lines are identical as viewed with journalctl --follow)

### EDIT 3

```
root@beaglebone:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: can0: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 10
    link/can
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 34:b1:f7:1b:02:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.252.60/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global eth0
4: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:01:02:03:04:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 78.78.88.67/29 scope global wwan0
```

### EDIT 2

In my opinion the first row looks suspicious.

```
netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         95.196.157.233  0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wwan0
95.196.157.232  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U         0 0          0 wwan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
```

### EDIT 0 & EDIT 1

As per comment by FloHimself below, the only subnet involved is `169.254.0.0/16` and one beginning with 192 is a typo. However, changing the static IP address doesn't keep the static IP from changing and the `ping -I wwan0` is still the only way to reach the world wide web.

Comment: Can you please append the output of `ip a` to the question and explain the subnets that are involved in your network? There are `169.254.0.0/16` and `192.254.0.0/16` on `eth0`?

Comment: I think you have found at least one of the bugs, I have a copy-paste error with 169/192 in my /etc/network/interfaces file.

This might explain why eth1 gets a new IP address from DHCP when the ethernet cable is attached.

I don't have access to the test rig again until the next week, so I can't post the output of "ip a" until then.

Thanks for the input!

Comment: I have done another edit with the correct 169.254 IP address. The behaviour is as before. Now I suspect there is some sort of conflict between `connmand` and the Avahi daemon.

I will also add the output from `netstat -rn`

Comment: Hi @FloHimself I've added the output of `ip a` under EDIT 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `telnet` to read the output from `journalctl --follow` I could see that `connmand` deleted routes whenever I tried to correct the routing table. So I disabled it using `systemctl`:

```
systemctl disable connman.service
```

I also modified `/etc/network/interfaces` to use a point-to-point configuration for `eth0`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 169.254.1.2
        netmask 255.255.0.0
        pointopoint 169.254.1.1
        gateway 169.254.1.1
        scope link
```

Then using `ifup eth0` the interface came up. Now I can `ping` both the remote endpoint of the eth0 cable `169.254.1.1` and `8.8.8.8` without using `ping -I N.N.N.N`.

### EDIT 0

The `eth0` never came up automatically at boot after disabling `connman` in `systemd` so I created a new `.service` file. So now everything works at boot time.

```
[Unit]
Description=Network interface eth0
Wants=network.target
Before=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "ifup eth0"
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "ifdown eth0"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```